# Randomizing characters and numerical values of letters

Tags: c

So I´ve read multiple answers and learnt different ways of generating random characters. I've come to like this attempt:

```
rand()%('z'-'a'+1)+'a';
```

I have used this method for quite a while, but I´ve come to understand that I can write it like this as well:

```
rand()%(26)+'a';
```

Now my question is, why does this work? What does the 'z'-'a' mean, and likewise, what does 26 mean? I know the characters have a numerical value, but that´s all I have been able to scrape from my attempts of trying to understand this.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: "What does 26 mean?" - the same thing it meant in grammar school: the number of letters in the english alphabet. Regarding the numerical value of things like literal `'a'` and `'z'`, see here: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com). Take the decimal value of `'z'`, subtract the decimal value of `'a'`, then add 1. And note: there are platforms where this does NOT calculate to 26 because the letters are not sequence contiguous ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)). The language standard only mandates *digit* (0..9) characters be contiguous.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the table. I guess my question is: Why does adding 26 to a with a (which has the value 97 according to the table) make it possible to generate the whole alphabet?

Comment: Do you understand the effect of `%` ?

Comment: You aren't adding 26 to `a`. You're adding `rand() % 26` to `a`

Comment: @LesterCrest They're not adding 26, they're adding `rand() % 26` to `'a'` . Operators have precedence. Modulo `%` has higher precedence than additive `+`, so the rand modulo calculation is done *first*, then the result (a value in 0..25) is added to `'a'`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not really.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, explains a lot

Comment: @LesterCrest If you don't know what the implications of the module operator `%` are, that's probably where you should start. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, valuable links, truly appreciate it.

Comment: Also note that, the way `rand()` and the modulo operator work, your code will not produce each letter in equal amounts -- `rand()` returns values between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, which is likely not evenly divisible by 26. Randomness in computers is a *really* tricky business. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Tricky business indeed. So how would you tackle that issue? Can RAND_MAX be changed?

Comment: No, `MAX_RAND` is set by the implementation. I'd have to look up usable C mechanics myself (me being more of the C++ persuation); I hoped that telling you where the problem sits would allow you to research the issue further if "good" randomness is what you aim for. Note that for *security* / cryptographic applications, `rand()` is altogether the wrong function to look at, and "rolling your own" is discouraged as a whole. You'd be better off looking at cryptographic libraries then (like openssl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a computer, letters are stored as numbers.

The lower-case letter `a` is stored as 97 and the lower-case letter `z` is stored as 122.

So the C expression `myVariable='a';` is the same as the C expression `myVariable=97;`.

On the other hand, `'z'-'a'+1` is the same as `122-97+1` which is the same as `26`.

Using the expression `rand()%26+'a'` you first generate a random number in the range 0...25 (using `rand()%26`). Then you add the value `97` to the result (because `xxx+'a'` is the same as `xxx+97`).

Note that `rand()%26+'a'` does not mean: `rand()%(26+'a')` but: `(rand()%26)+'a'`.

As a result, you have a random number in the range 97...122.

This is the range of numbers that represent the lower-case letters `a`...`z`.

Comment: Oh man, thx for this.

Comment: Wanted to ask for the implications of this, but as I like to try things out for myself, I wrote a quick code to check things. int myvariable;
 char myvariable1;
 
 myvariable = 97;
 myvariable1 = 97;
 printf(" %d %c", myvariable, myvariable1); .     It ran the way I thought it would, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the ASCII value for all of these characters. You just need to search for the ASCII Table and you'll find out that the ASCII value for 'a' is 97, and for 'z' is 122. Therefore (122-97+1) is equal to 26. When you store a char into a variabile, you are storing its ASCII value, thus operators such as +, -, ... Are done using the ASCII value of their addends.